# System.InvalidOperationException: Reading is already in progress thrown by api-gateway like application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

This is how my C# app works. I'm getting a request and I want to pass it to a downstream service, so yes, I'm acting as a api-gateway. Problem is that I'm seeing `System.InvalidOperationException: Reading is already in progress` exceptions.

The code goes like this:

```
// map request
HttpRequest request = GetOriginalRequest();
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Content = MapContent(request),
    Method = MapMethod(request),
    RequestUri = MapUri(request)
};
...
// send request
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage); // throws here!!!
```

The MapContent method looks like this:

```
...
request.EnableBuffering(); // it throws if I don't do this
request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
content.Headers.ContentLength = request.ContentLength;
return new StreamContent(request.Body);
```

This is the Exception data:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Reading is already in progress.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.VerifyIsNotReading()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.TryReadInternal(ReadResult& readResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody.OnConsumeAsync()
```

I have obviously omitted many details and code but this is the essence.

Any idea how to reuse the stream to pass it to another service? THE CONTENT CANNOT BE COPIED since this will have a big performance degradation, so this is not acceptable `var content = new ByteArrayContent(await ToByteArray(request.Body));`

Thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: This looks like a bug, can you file an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore. Can you show *all* of your code?

Comment: `OnConsumeAsync` This runs after middleware completes. Is `var content = new ByteArrayContent(await ToByteArray(request.Body));` running in the background?

Comment: @halter73 not at all, it runs as part of one of the middlewares we have setup

Comment: @davidfowl Will do. Thank you!

Comment: @davidfowl https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33409